# How to add values of duplicate keys in associative arrays, using Shell Script?

Tags: arrays, shell, sh, associative

I'm having trouble removing duplicate keys with the lower value.

I've used a while loop to loop through the file with `while read key value`.

The Original text file looks like this:

```
meson 6
electron 5
meson 12
neutron 10
proton 5
hadron 7
neutron 10
proton 2
proton 8
```

This is my output so far using associative arrays in shell:

```
electron 5
hadron 7
meson 18
meson 6
neutron 10
neutron 20
proton 15
proton 5
proton 7
```

I summed up the values of the same keys but I want to remove the key with the lower value.

My desired output is this:

```
electron 5
hadron 7
meson 18
neutron 20
proton 15
```

Is there a way of returning the higher value only and then finishing off the script with `sort`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash version 4 -- `sh` does not have associative arrays

```
declare -A sum

while read key value; do ((sum[$key] += value)); done <file

for key in "${!sum[@]}"; do echo $key ${sum[$key]}; done
```

```
proton  15
neutron  20
hadron  7
electron  5
meson  18
```

Associative array keys have no natural ordering. You can pipe that for loop into `sort` or `sort -k2n` if you wish.

Comment: if `sh` doesn't have associative arrays, is it possible to mimic them with string manipulation?

Comment: Why would you want to go down that road? Use an appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

awk can do associate array as well. Try this awk

```
awk '!($1 in a) || a[$1] < $2{a[$1]=$2; next} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
neutron 10
electron 5
proton 8
hadron 7
meson 12
```

Comment: I was looking for a non-`awk` solution, is it possible to solve this without `awk`?

Comment: What is the problem with awk. Same one line in shell or any other tool will be much bigger code.